# lua c api: how to push a string with a null character in the middle?

Tags: c, api, lua

normally, I would just use

```
lua_pushstring(lua_State* L, const char* s);
```

however, the string I want to push might have a null character in it. How do I make that work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`lua_pushlstring`](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_pushlstring).

```
void lua_pushlstring (lua_State *L, const char *s, size_t len);
```

> Pushes the string pointed to by s with
>   size len onto the stack. Lua makes (or
>   reuses) an internal copy of the given
>   string, so the memory at s can be
>   freed or reused immediately after the
>   function returns. The string can
>   contain embedded zeros.